# Half Edge data structure mesh - OpenMesh C++ - Boundary halfedges in edge

Tags: c++

In mesh - half-edge data structure, there are **edges** and **half-edges**.

Not necessary in OpenMesh library, edge has usually a method which gives first half edge:

```
Halfedge h = mesh.halfedge(e, 0);  // e - is an edge in mesh; 0 - id of halfedge in edge
```

And for opposite edge I use :

```
Halfedge h = mesh.halfedge(e, 1);
```

This edge function looks like this in the library:

```
/// returns the \c i'th halfedge of edge \c e. \c i has to be 0 or 1.
Halfedge halfedge(Edge e, unsigned int i) const
{
    assert(i<=1);
    return Halfedge((e.idx() << 1) + i);
}
```

- Would this function return first half edge if only one of half-edges in a pair exist?
- Is the last line of pseudo-code valid for **boundary** edges
  too?
- How many half-edges boundary edges have?
- Do edges in half edge data structure have 1 or 2  halfedges on the
  boundary?

Answer (score 0):

I can give a part answer to your questions :

As far as I have explored the subject in OpenMesh data structure, all edges are split into 2 half-edges, including edges on the boundary of your mesh. In fact, **edges do not exist** literally speaking, only pairs of half-edges do.

Thus said, I only work with OpenMesh library and I don't know the behaviour of other libraries and data structures using half-edges.

Hope this helps.